# DetachedCriteria - Group by

Tags: java, hibernate

I do a search by using a detached, and I've to use a group by.  My code is bellow :

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
@Override
public List<Dossier> rechercher(DossierBean critere)
throws TechnicalException {
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Dossier.class);

    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("firstName", critere.getFirstName()));
    criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("secondName", critere.getSecondName()));
    criteria.add((Criterion) Projections.groupProperty("iddossier"));
    List<Dossier> dList = findByCriteria(criteria);
    return dList;
}
```

I get this exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.criterion.PropertyProjection cannot
     be cast to org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion
```

I know that `groupProperty(...)` is the problem, but I cannot ignore my group by because I'll get a double lines.  Any suggestion?

Comment: can you your entity details for `Dossier` to the post?

Comment: this is just a part of my detached criteria, my Dossier entity contains a lists of objects, and I've to do a group by iddossier to ignore all double.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add projections to DetachedCriteria use setProjection() method for that as in example below:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Dossier.class);

criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("firstName", critere.getFirstName()));
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("secondName", critere.getSecondName()));
criteria.setProjection(Projections.groupProperty("iddossier"));
```

Comment: this return only **iddossier**, and not the dossier **object**.